# REDSHIFT: how to remove special character in Boolean variable from redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, boolean, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I have a Boolean variable in redshift  and the values I have in that is true and false.

when it displayed in redshift it comes with a "." (dot) for true,  due to the fact that is 4 characters and false is 5 characters.
[image]

we are trying to remove the "." in redshift.

all the replace functions in redshift are for string not for Boolean.

how can we see the 'true' without a "." (dot) in redshift?

Comment: What bench are you using?  Boolean values are stored as binary bits so there is no characters to modify.  You bench or possibly the JDBC/ODBC connector is configured in some way to present the data this way.

Comment: The dot seems to be generated by your SQL Client. It probably isn't impacting your column. To test this, you could `SELECT col1, col1 = TRUE FROM table` and see whether the two output columns match.